# Kiwi-tcms Django plugin installation PROBLEMS

Tags: python, django, kiwi-tcms

Hi I got an error when I try to install kiwi-tcms Django plugin in Ubuntu.
I run this command as the documentation says
**Command:** `pip install kiwitcms-django-plugin`
**Documentation:** https://github.com/kiwitcms/django-plugin

The error message in the console
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-kdc6s2yz/gssapi/

I really tried different kind of things to solve it but I didn't get any new good result

Why could be the error ?

Comment: Paste the error from below the line Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:

Comment: Show us the actual error in the first place if you want help.